# Html/Javascript/Css how to check if inputs are empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input

I have 6 different input-fields and I want to do so you have to fill in all of them, else a alert message will pop-up. Any tips on how to do this?

I also have problems with option for different `font-style`s. When you click on the different options for the `font-style`, the text that you wrote in the input-filed should change and also the text infront "förtag" and so on.

This is my code:

```js
function SkrivUt() {
  var el = document.getElementById('f');
  el.style.color = document.getElementById('textColor').value;
  el.style.fontStyle = document.getElementById('selectedFont').value;
  el.style.backgroundColor = document.getElementById('backGroundColour').value;

  $("#area1").html($("#foretagText").val());
  $("#area2").html($("#efternamnText").val());
  $("#area3").html($("#fornamnNamnText").val());
  $("#area4").html($("#titleText").val());
  $("#area5").html($("#telefonText").val());
  $("#area6").html($("#epostText").val());
  $("#visitkort").hide();
  $("#visitkortsDemo").show();
}

function reset() {
  document.getElementById('foretagText').value = "";
  document.getElementById('efternamnText').value = "";
  document.getElementById('fornamnNamnText').value = "";
  document.getElementById('titleText').value = "";
  document.getElementById('telefonText').value = "";
  document.getElementById('epostText').value = "";
}
```

```css
.form-style-3 {
  max-width: 400px;
  max-height 400px;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
}
.form-style-3 label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.form-style-3 label span {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
.form-style-3 fieldset {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  border: 1px solid #FFD2D2;
  padding: 20px;
  background: lightblue;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 15px #FFE5E5;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 15px #FFE5E5;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 15px #FFE5E5;
}
/*Format legent inom ett fieldset*/

.form-style-3 fieldset legend {
  color: #FFA0C9;
  border-top: 1px solid #FFD2D2;
  border-left: 1px solid #FFD2D2;
  border-right: 1px solid #FFD2D2;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  background: #FFF4F4;
  padding: 0px 8px 3px 8px;
  box-shadow: -0px -1px 2px #F1F1F1;
  -moz-box-shadow: -0px -1px 2px #F1F1F1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -0px -1px 2px #F1F1F1;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.select-field {
  background: gray;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
.input-field {
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  color: red
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Visitkort</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='Style.css' />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="form-style-3">
    <div id="visitkort" style='display:block'>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Visitkort</legend>
        <label><span>Företaget</span>
          <input type="text" id="foretagText" />
        </label>
        <label><span>Efternamn </span>
          <input type="text" id="efternamnText" />
        </label>
        <label><span>Förnamn </span>
          <input type="text" id="fornamnNamnText" />
        </label>
        <label><span>Titel </span>
          <input type="text" id="titleText" />
        </label>
        <label><span>Telefon </span>
          <input type="text" id="telefonText" />
        </label>
        <label><span>Epost </span>
          <input type="text" id="epostText" />
        </label>
        <label>
          <span>Välj bakgrundsfärg</span>
          <select class="select-field" id="backGroundColour">
            <option value="RoyalBlue">Blå</option>
            <option value="Yellow">gul</option>
            <option value="Crimson">Röd</option>
          </select>
        </label>
        <label>
          <span>Välj Textfärg</span>
          <select class="select-field" id="textColor">
            <option value="RoyalBlue">Blå</option>
            <option value="Yellow">Gul</option>
            <option value="Crimson">röd</option>
          </select>
        </label>
        <label>
          <span>Välj typsnitt</span>
          <select class="select-field" id="selectedFont">
            <option value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
            <option value="Ariel">Ariel</option>
            <option value="Impact">Impact</option>
            <option value="Tahoma">Tahoma</option>
          </select>
        </label>

        <label><span><button type="button" onclick="reset()">Nollställ</button></span><span><button type="button"  onclick="SkrivUt()">Skriv ut</button></span>
        </label>

      </fieldset>

    </div>

    <div id="visitkortsDemo" style='display:none'>
      <fieldset id="f">
        <legend>Förgranskning av visitkort</legend>
n>Företaget </span>
          <p id="area1"></p>
        </label>
        <label><span>Efternamn </span>
          <p id="area2"></p>
        </label>
        <label><span>Förnamn </span>
          <p id="area3"></p>
        </label>
        <label><span>Titel </span>
          <p id="area4"></p>
        </label>
        <label><span>Telefon </span>
          <p id="area5"></p>
        </label>
        <label><span>Epost </span>
          <p id="area6"></p>
        </label>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple and quick way would be to use HTML5's [`required`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) attribute!

Example:

```
<input type="text" id="foretagText" required />
```

This will produce browser alerts, when an input field is empty. No need for difficult custom Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't tried much, so im not just going to give answer, but here is an idea, in raw javascript. You will want a better way of collecting the input Ids obviously, thats up to you.

```
<script>

var inputs = ["inputid1", "inputid2", "inputid3"];
var notFilled = "";
for (var i in inputs){
     element = document.getElementById(i);
     if(element.value==""){
         notFilled = i;
         break;
     }
}

if(notFilled!=""){
   alert("you must fill" + notFilled);

}

</script>
```

Comment: sorry, but this is a pretty poor solution for a few reasons - very surprised its getting upvoted...

Comment: Oh I know... But it's based on what he has given me. I would not do it this way and not use raw js like this.

Comment: it would better practice to either `break` from the loop though when you find one that isnt filled out, or use `Array.prototype.some()`.  Also dont use negative variable names, it makes code much harder to read.

Comment: Certainly would. was rather rushed. Updated!

Answer (score 2):

```
// create your err array
var err = [];

//test if values are a blank string
if($("#foretagText").val() === ""){

 //add the error message to your error array
  err.push("Foretag not entered");

}
// be sure you only have if statements and they aren't nested like this
if($("#idOfNextValue").val() === ""){

 //add the error message to your error array
  err.push("Foretag not entered");

}
//alert all messages in your error array.
alert (err.length + " Errors:<br>" +err.join("<br>"));//join
```

Comment: Thank you! Can I do so I get a pop-up every time some of the input-fields are empty and not only one? :)

Comment: yes you make an if statement for all your values. then instead of making it alert in the if statement you just put the text in an array to hold all your error messages. then join your array with an array.join("<br>") and alert that message. I did an edit to my code for an example.

Comment: also make sure they are all different separate if statements. so that every test will run

Comment: Would be great if you add a brief explanation with your code snippet.

Comment: look good now? @ianaya89

Comment: @TravisHallet Much better!

Answer (score 1):

In HTML5 you can use required attribute as follow;

```
<input type="text" required>
```

Or in jQuery:

Let's say HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="input-1">
<input type="text" id="input-2">
<input type="text" id="input-3">
<input type="text" id="input-4">
```

and so on..

Now jQuery

```
if($("[id^=input]").val()=="")
{
  alert("error");
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML way : Use required attribute

```
<input type="text" id="somename" required>
```

Javascript way:

```
if ($('#foretagText').val() == '' || $('#efternamnText').val() != ' ...) {
   alert("Fields empty");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first question. To require the user to select a value in a select you have to add the atributte required like this

```
                    <select class="select-field" id="backGroundColour" required>
                        <option value="RoyalBlue">Blå</option>
                        <option value="Yellow">gul</option>
                        <option value="Crimson">Röd</option>
                    </select></label>
```

For your second question I'm not completely sure about this but I think that the problem resides in that you are trying to change the label style directly without change the associated css.